# Accessing array values in optional chaning

Tags: javascript

Could someone, please, explain to me why doesn't the first case throw an error here?

```js
const target = {}

console.log("I won't throw: ", target.some?.property[0])

const value = target.some?.property
console.log("I will throw: ", value[0])
```

Here's an example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-currying-wb27l

Comment: have you tried reversing the order of the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bracket notation has the same operator precedence as dot notation. They do the exact same sort of thing. Another way of looking at it is that the following won't throw:

```js
const target = {}

console.log("I won't throw: ", target.some?.property.someProperty);
```

except with `[0]` instead of `someProperty`.

If the optional chaining `?.` stops at a certain point, any further property access down the line will not occur, and the whole expression evaluates to `undefined`.

In contrast, with

```
const value = target.some?.property
console.log("I will throw: ", value[0])
```

Here, `value` is assigned `undefined`, since `some` doesn't exist. Then, `value[0]` throws because you can't access properties of `undefined`.

With optional chaining, further property access will occur, in the same expression, *if* the chaining succeeds. In the same expression, if the chaining fails, further property access will not occur. But that's only when considering the *same expression*. Once the expression containing optional chaining has been evaluated (here, it gets assigned to a variable), the special logic provided by optional chaining no longer applies.